# Strange spacing in twitter bootstrap top navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Twitter Bootstrap to create a navbar across the top of a page which has several dropdown menus. For some reason, the first list element aligns to the bottom of the bar by virtue of a empty link that fills the top space.  I copied this first term for the other list items, but none of the other elements align to the bottom or have an empty link.  Any ideas for how i can fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nav Mockup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">

            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">NCTL<a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >About NCTL <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Challenge / Links</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">STEM Equity</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Slannis Message</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Supporters</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MOS Press Room</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                   
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Education Programs <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">K12 Classroom</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Museum Based</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Traveling</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Advocacy <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Achievements</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Video Links</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >News <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Enews Archive</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">NCTL Studies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Media Coverage</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: A Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You a error in your markup

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">NCTL<a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">NCTL</a>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1440c8a6/8/)**